# Adding font-awesome to Omega 4 subtheme

Tags: 7, theming

I want to use [font-awesome](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/) in an Omega 4 subtheme. I added this line to `Gemfile`:

```
  gem 'font-awesome-sass'
```

and tried to import it in `subtheme.styles.scss` with:

```
@import "font-awesome-sass";
```

But I get this error after running `compass compile`:

```
"Syntax error: File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome-sass.
```

I also tried `@import "font-awesome-sass.css"` with no error, but no new stylesheet file is added to the subtheme pages.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Adding it to the Gemfile alone doesn't install the library. The Gemfile is used by a program called Bundler that manages your Ruby gems for you. You need to make sure you have this installed with `sudo gem install bundler` and then run `bundle install` where the Gemfile is located (your theme directory).

Alternatively you could just install font-awesome-sass yourself with `sudo gem install font-awesome-sass`.

Comment: I have also run this command (`bundle install`), and `bundle show font-awesome-sass` shows that it is installed correctly